# split out the key and the value?

Tags: php

the array shows as this:

```
$_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'] = "Jump to Page";
$_ADMINLANG['global']['go'] = "Go";
$_ADMINLANG['months']['january'] = "January";
$_ADMINLANG['months']['february'] = "February";
.......
```

now, i want to  output the above data as this:

```
 $_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'] =
 $_ADMINLANG['global']['go'] =
 $_ADMINLANG['months']['january'] =
 "Jump to Page";
"Go";
"January";
```

how do i do ? thank you.

Comment: I have a cake. \*teh codez\*. Really, we need **more detail**; what do you want to do, what do you want to get out of it?

Comment: Not clear what your question is. What is the desired output. What is your code? What about: `echo "$_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'] = " . '"' . $_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'] . '"';`?

Comment: `echo $_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'];` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply print the values as you mentioned, then this must be the code.

```
$temp = '';
foreach ($_ADMINLANG as $key1 => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key2 => $val) {
        echo  '$_ADMINLANG["'.$key1.'"]["'.$key2.'"] = <br />';
        $temp .= $val.'<br/>';
    }
}
echo $temp;
```

Comment: the key is "mergefields", i want to output as this 'mergefields'. how to alter it?

Comment: i changed to this     echo  "$_ADMINLANG['".$key1."']['".$key2."']". '<br />';.but the IDE shows an error

Comment: the line  `"$_ADMINLANG['".$key1."']['".$key2."']".'<br />'` must be correct

Comment: how do u want a mergefields to be?

Answer (score 0):

just loop through the array and echo the keys (first output) and for the second output echo the values.

have a look at the foreach function: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: foreach (array_expression as $key => $value) i don't know how to write the array_expression to my example? $_ADMINLANG[][] ? am i right?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php - returns keys of array

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php - returns values of array

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this is just about outputting the array contents, but if it is, here you go:

```
$_ADMINLANG['global']['jumppage'] = "Jump to Page";
$_ADMINLANG['global']['go'] = "Go";
$_ADMINLANG['months']['january'] = "January";
$_ADMINLANG['months']['february'] = "February";

foreach ($_ADMINLANG as $sub) {
    foreach ($sub as $key => $val) {
        echo $val, '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: but there is no output like this: $_ADMINLANG['global']['go']

Comment: @zhuanzhou Ahh, you want to literally display the array definition? Can I ask what you need this for? Maybe there are better ways to do things?